# Beginning transaction twice before committing the first time?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, transactions

Can we begin a transaction twice before committing it the first time?

```
public static void functionXYZ(ABC bean)throws DataAccessException {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        
        //
        do something with bean
        //
        session = //write code to start the session
        tx = session.beginTransaction();   //1st beginTransaction()
        tx.begin();  //2nd begin()

        session.saveOrUpdate(bean);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        

    } catch (Exception e) { .... }}
```

I understand maybe - getTransaction() is a better alternative in place of the first beginTransaction() or maybe just remove second tx.begin(), BUT, if I do exactly as in the code -

Is it alright to do 2 begin on the transaction right after each other? Will it throw any error?

Comment: What does the JavaDoc say on this?

Comment: @Thomas As far as I could find, JavaDoc does not say anything about this explicitly.